# why is the file creation time not getting updated when I delete and copy it in?

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I'm running the following to delete and re-add a set of files.  We're trying to confirm *when* a set of files were copied programmatically.

```
            #delete
            Get-ChildItem "$webServerFilePathUnc\*" -exclude $logsPath | Remove-Item -recurse

            #re-add
            Copy-Item -Force -Recurse "$($packageTmpFolder.FullName)\*" -Destination $webServerFilePathUnc
```

Everything I know about the Windows filesystem says `FileSystemInfo.CreationTime` should be updated when you delete and copy-in a file, but we're not seeing that in practice.  Files that we deleted and copied in have stale CreationTime values predating the copy.

In my case, all files are reporting "‎Monday, ‎January ‎25, ‎2021, ‏‎2:16:41 PM" or thereabouts for the Creation Time, despite the fact that I just deleted, unzipped, then copied the files to that target location.  This is fairly uniform across the entire folder - a directory full of over 500 dlls.  All that I've checked say January 25th.  So it's too large to be a timezone issue, and if it's caching then the caching is pathological.

These are all files on the local drive of a VM that I'm manipulating via UNC.

Comment: How big is the time difference? Could it be a local time vs UTC issue? Is it the same time difference for all files? Is it the same creation time as the original file? Examples would help...

Comment: You did not "create" that file as it already exists, you are just copying it.

Comment: Sry, that wasn't quite correct as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @newone yes, I see the cause - FileSystemTunnelling.  A file that's deleted and then re-created in under 15 seconds does not get an updated CreationTime.

Comment: As @Pxtl already mentioned. FS Tunneling is your issue. 15 seconds is the threshold. Simply add a delay of 15 seconds between "delete" and "copy".

Comment: PS: See ( https://gist.github.com/danzek/624d5c3aaa349f0e846281c75c2ec371 ) and the old ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923 )

Comment: Maybe an alternative is to use post-processing: You can always edit the creationTime `$targetFile.CreationTime = $sourceFile.CreationTime`